# How can i check if shape:[] is null in json with php

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have a json object like this :

```
{"Techne":{"@Version":"2.2","Author":"ZeuX","Name":"","PreviewImage":"","ProjectName":"","ProjectType":"","Description":"","DateCreated":"","Models":[{"Model":{"GlScale":"1,1,1","Name":"","TextureSize":"1,1","@texture":"texture.png","BaseClass":"ModelBase","Geometry":{"Folder":[],"Shape":[],"Piece":[],"Null":[]}}}]}}
```

How can I check if the array Shape:[] is empty with PHP I only know how to do it with JavaScript but this matter needs PHP to be used how can I do it?

Comment: `json_decode` the string, then check the count of the property. http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: But how do I access the property it's inside 3 other objects

Comment: The same way you would with any object in PHP. If you don't know how, then I'd suggest looking at some tutorials first.

Comment: Lol I'm way more familiar with JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then access it's members.

```
$json = json_decode('{"Techne":{"@Version":"2.2","Author":"ZeuX","Name":"","PreviewImage":"","ProjectName":"","ProjectType":"","Description":"","DateCreated":"","Models":[{"Model":{"GlScale":"1,1,1","Name":"","TextureSize":"1,1","@texture":"texture.png","BaseClass":"ModelBase","Geometry":{"Folder":[],"Shape":[],"Piece":[],"Null":[]}}}]}}');

if(empty($json->Techne->Models[0]->Model->Geometry->Shape))
    echo "Shape is empty";
```

`json_decode()` will give you an object in this case, because that is how this JSON string is formatted. You can learn more by searching about JSON and PHP, there are plenty of tutorials that will help you understand better.

I hope it helped you.

Comment: Thanks sooo much this was the perfect peace of code for the job!

Comment: You are welcome ! Remember to look at the PHP Doc for more info.

Comment: I will it's very similar to $each in jquery